# Magento 2 minicart showing count multiple time

Tags: mini-cart, magento2.1.6

I am using magento 2.1.6 and i have a problem with my mini cart. the minicart showing multiple count at a time if i added 1 product it show "11 items" . and also if there is no product in cart it just only show the count "0" the label is not displaying please see the attachment

[image: Multiple count]

[image: count with out label when count=0]

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
?>

<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
        <div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getConfig()); ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you integrating a theme?

Comment: @ Saphal Jha  yes currently i'm using porto theme at the first time the cart show nothing so i added the default magento minicart.phtml file and data file after that this issue occured

Comment: Check your minicart.phtml code.

Comment: @ S H Patel i have checked it nothing find can you please check it

Comment: Could you please run content deploy command and test it again?

Comment: @Saphal Jha i have tested those method already now also i have run the command but the same effect

Answer (score 1):

Hey i have resolved the issue by making some changes on this section

```
<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
```

Now the correct full code is

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
?>

<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number">
            <!-- ko if: !getCartParam('summary_count') -->
            <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko i18n: 'item' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
        <div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getConfig()); ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```